# Distributing $n$ different things among $r$ persons

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How can  $10$ **different** pencils be distributed among $3$ students?

#### MY TRY $1$

total ways $= 3^{10}$

#### MY TRY $2$

$10 \times 9 \times 8 =720$

Which one is correct? If both are wrong what is correct answer? And please explain the approach.

### EDIT

A query just came in my mind after the comment on this question... As he said $3^10$ is correct. Then my question is: **if there were $n$ identical things** (i.e. $10$ identical pencils) would the answer be same, $3^{10}$? Or would it be $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ i.e.  $\binom{12}2$ then?

Comment: Your first one would be correct, since each pencil has 3 ways of distributing and there are 10 pencils

Comment: why not second one???

Comment: because the second one would representing the number of ways you can choose 3 pencils from 10, without replacement.

Comment: if it was identical would the answer be same???

Comment: No, there would be less ways of distributing the pencils if they were identical

Comment: what is that???? ... i have edited the post ...please can u give me a full reply

Comment: I will give you an example, take for example pencils labeled a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j. Then, distributing it in a manner as (a,b)(c,d)(e,f,g,h,i,j) is different than (a,c)(b,d)(e,f,g,h,i,j). If the pencils were identical, then the answer would simply be (2)(2)(6). As you can see, there are a lot more ways if pencils were different

Comment: what will be the answer then (n+r-1)C(r-1) ... i.e. 12C2

Comment: it will be a [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29), which is a whole new cup of tea. The question then becomes - how many ways can you choose 3 numbers from 0-10, with replacement such that they add up to 10

Answer (score 5):

As stated in comments the correct answer is $3^{10}$.

Now I will tell you what to do for identical pencils. You have to find how many ways can you distribute $10$ pencils to $3$ people. Let the number of pencils with each one be $a,b,c$

Clearly, $a+b+c=10$

Also $a,b,c$ are whole numbers. Now here is the trick.

Add 3 to both sides of equations and rename

$a+1=A$

$b+1=B$

$c+1=C$

This won't affect the number of your solutions.
Hence, $A+B+C=13$ Why did I do so? See :
 You can write 13 as $1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1$

I'm not kidding. Now see left side. How many $+$ signs you see? And on the right?

Obviously, 2 on the left and 12 on the right. Now you just have to choose 2 plus signs on the right for that and the $1+1...$ which remain will form a number. Clearly, all these ways will be a solution to your problem. Marvelous, isn't it?

So the answer is $\binom{12}{2}$. No need to mug all those formulas...

Comment: Why is this answer $suddenly$ getting upvotes?

Comment: @vonbrand you seem to have a good vocabulary...bletcherous Although I prefer that notation.

Comment: Because I think your way of explaining it is nice. Even if I consider your taste in notation less than stellar.

Comment: Well everything is relative... Anyways you really have a good vocabulary