# Probability [Sum of digits is even for a random number]

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

A number of 6 digit numbers is written down at random. Probability that the sum of the digits is an even number is? Please answer with explanation.

Comment: Does the first digit have to be nonzero? I would assume yes since you said number but it is better to be clear.

Comment: Its not given in the question. So, lets assume the first digit to be non-zero.

Comment: If we have five digits given, then note that we can extend those five digits with a sixth. How does this process of extending the number affect parity?

Comment: What have _you_ tried so far?

Comment: I guess there's an alternate form of this question that omits the restriction to 6-digit numbers. In that case, I think the answer is not well defined, because there is no notion of a uniform probability distribution on the natural numbers. For example, the numbers divisible by 3 can be put in a one-to-one correspondence with the numbers not divisible by 3, but that doesn't mean that the probability of getting a number divisible by 3 is 1/2. Nor is it 1/3.

Comment: @BenCrowell You might be interested in the notion of _Natural Density_ of a set of natural numbers ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density ). By that metric, there's a well-defined answer to your alternate question question; using the techniques in any of this question's answers the limit is easily seen to be $\frac12$, since for all $n$ the number of $m\leq n$ with even digit-sum is within one of $\frac n2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is independent of whether the first digit has to be zero or not. By the same logic as my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/704328/1508), the answer is immediately seen to be $\frac12$.

Comment: The answer is 1/2. But, could you please explain.

Comment: @Monique: Did you look at the link I provided? That has explanation enough.

Comment: ok, got it. Thanks :D

Answer (score 5):

Let $p_n $ be the probability that an $n$-digit number has even parity.

We see that $p_1 = {1 \over 2}$.

Suppose we are given an $n$ digit number and add one digit. Then there are two ways the $n+1$ digit number can have even parity: (1) The $n$ digit number has even parity and the new digit is even, and (2) the $n$ digit number has odd parity and the new digit is odd.

Then $p_{n+1} = {1 \over  2} p_n + {1 \over 2} (1- p_n) = { 1 \over 2}$.

Comment: $\frac12$ is intuitively obvious too. :) I doubt OP will understand the recurrence. :p

Comment: @Sabyasachi: I will elaborate a little.

Comment: yeah that's good. :)

Comment: +1 for recurrence. although i *still* don't see why we are calculating anything at all. even and odd are obviously *evenly* distributed. (yes I make terrible puns)

Comment: I think is it good to look at the same problem in different ways. I have often made mistakes with what was in hindsight obvious.

Comment: I agree.${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: think of choosing the first five digits, then the last digit. If the sum of the first five digits is odd, the sixth digit has to be odd to make the sum of all six even. What is the chance of this? If the sum of the first five is even,....

Comment: Yes, that's how I started. But, then there would be many ways of choosing the first five digits so that sum is odd and same for even sum. So, I couldn't figure out.

Comment: The point is that it doesn't matter how many ways there are to pick the first five digits.  Whether the sum of the first five is odd or even, the chance the sum of the six is even is $\frac 12$

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the probability that the sum of the first (leftmost) five digits is even. Then the probability that the sum of the first five digits is odd is $1-p$.

Now let us find the probability that the sum of all the digits is even. This can happen in two disjoint ways: (i) The sum of the first five is even, and the last is even or (ii) the sum of the first five is odd, and the last is odd.

The probability of (i) is $(p)(1/2)$. The probability of (ii) is $(1-p)(1/2)$. Add. We get $1/2$.

**Remark:** There is  more "bijective" way of seeing this. Let $E$ be the set of numbers with even digit sum, and $O$ the set of numbers with odd digit sum.

If $e$ is a digit string in $E$, let $\varphi(e)$ be the digit string obtained by replacing the last digit of $e$ by $9$ minus the last digit of $e$.

Then $\varphi(e)$ has odd digit sum, and all numbers in $O$ can be obtained in this way. It follows that $E$ and $O$ have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note down all the cases where a $6$ digit number can have its sum of digits even.

$1.$ All $6$ digits even: Is this possible? Yes. With repetition.

$2.$ $4$ digits even($2$ digits odd): Is this possible? Yes. With/Without repetition.

$3.$ $2$ digits even($4$ digits odd): Is this possible? Yes. Yes. With/Without repetition.

$4.$ $6$ digits odd. Is this possible? Yes. With repetition.

Comment: Why do you think the digits must be different?

Comment: the final answer will be?

Comment: @Monique you need to do that yourself.

Comment: @Monique you really should exhibit some work yourself, that would give us some reason to give more hints, if needed

Comment: @gt6989b *precisely*

Comment: i tried and couldn't get it right. That's why I'm asking it here.

Comment: @Monique why don't you try to answer the numbered points in this answer. we will be happy to provide more hints then.

Comment: @gt6989b too late for that.. ready made answers already in.

Comment: All that work is completely unnecessary. See my answer.