# Probability of sums with 6 dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You roll six independent fair dice.

What is the probability that their sum is divisible by 6?

I don't really know where to start. Does the ordering of the dice matter? (1,2,2,2,2,3) vs (3,2,2,2,2,1). I feel like it does. I'm not strong with counting arguments so I don't know how to find the number of ways that you can arrange that.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  Whatever be the sum of the first five, the probability that adding the sixth number will give a number divisible by $6$ is $\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: +1 Actually my biggest [reputation catch](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1523831/75923) ever.